# Вывод близлежащих объектов

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Как при отображении метки на карте вывести метки самых близких к ней соц. объектов (школа, д. сад, магазин, больница, кинотеатр)

Answer (score 1):

Можно с использованием API Поиска по организациям (https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/geosearch/ ) получить координаты близлежащих объектов и вывести их метки. Обратите внимание на условия использования API.

Для решения вашей задачи будут полезны следующие query-параметры:

```
text=<поисковый запрос>
type=biz (тип объектов)
ll=<координаты метки>
spn=<размеры области поиска>
rspn=1 (не искать за пределами области поиска)
```

Вот примеры запросов: https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/geosearch/doc/examples/geosearch_examples-docpage/